# Directory tree in a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, directory, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I'm using [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) and [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) Python modules to open, extract and compress archives.
I need to display the archive structure in a QTreeWidget, and I don't know how to go on. To get the infos I use the function `infos(path)` from [this file](https://gist.github.com/766505).
I would like to obtain something like this (from Ark):
[image]

For example, if I receive this filenames: `('GCI/PyFiles/prova3.py', 'GCI/', 'GCI/PyFiles/', 'GCI/Screenshots/', 'GCI/prova2.py', 'prova.py')`, I'd like to obtain this:

```
- prova.py
- GCI/
    |
    |- prova2.py
    |- PyFiles/
             |- prova3.py
    |- Screenshots/
```

in my QTreeWidget.

Thank you,
rubik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how QTreeWidget wants it's data offhand, but here is a (possibly bad way) to build the structure in memory.

```
x = ('GCI/PyFiles/prova3.py', 'GCI/', \
     'GCI/PyFiles/', 'GCI/Screenshots/', \
     'GCI/prova2.py', 'prova.py')

structure = {}
for fn in x:
    path = fn.split('/')

    tmpd = structure
    for p in path[:-1]:
        try:
            tmpd = tmpd[p]
        except KeyError:
            tmpd = tmpd[p] = {}

    tmpd[path[-1]] = None
```

This will give you a dictionary `structure` that for each key is either another dictionary (representing a folder) or `None` representing that the key is a file.

The better way to do this would create a class like this:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dirs = {}
        self.files = []
```

or something like that which you can populate.  If I remember correctly from my QT programming days, the QTreeWidget wants a datasource so you basically could figure out what that source looks like and populate it appropriately.  There's also probably the option to do this,

```
[sp for _,sp in sorted(
         (len(splitpath),splitpath) for splitpath in
            (path.split('/') for path in x)
         )
    ]
```

which would return you:

```
[['prova.py'], ['GCI', ''], ['GCI', 'prova2.py'], 
 ['GCI', 'PyFiles', ''], ['GCI', 'PyFiles', 'prova3.py'], 
 ['GCI', 'Screenshots', '']]
```